# Windows is installed but can't boot on it

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows

I'm from windows. I have installed ubuntu for dual boot but actually my computer directly launch on Ubuntu. I still have my windows nfts driver as you can see on the logs. But can't boot on it with grub.
I'm french, my english is not that good. Thanks for helping,

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/nbfFCMQF8c/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running: `sudo os-prober`

If Windows is listed, open `/etc/default/grub` and add this line:
`GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false`

Then run `sudo update-grub`

You should be able to see Windows after reboot

Comment: You're a fucking boss